# django send_email() shows success but no email received

Tags: django, smtp, django-email

I am learning how to send an email in `Djgnao`. I have configured

```
# settings.py
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'

EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = '<my username>@gmail.com'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '<my password>'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

and in `django shell` I try to send an email to my self (and my friend also)

```
>>> from django.core.mail import send_mail
>>> send_mail('Subject here', 'Here is the message.', "<my username>@gmail.com", ["<my username>@gmail.com"])
```

and it returns result which looks successful

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Subject: Subject here
From: <my username>@gmail.com
To: <my username>@gmail.com
Date: Wed, 21 Jan 2015 17:55:20 -0000
Message-ID: <20150121175520.31612.19817@<my username>>

Here is the message.
---------------------------------------------------------------------
1
```

But checking my email and my friend's email inbox, there is no such email received.

Am I misunderstanding something? Or do I need to do something with my Gmail account?

---

Actually, I tried the [Sign in to Admin Console] in https://support.google.com/a/answer/182076?hl=en, but I got redirected in between "re-enter your password" page and "choose an account or add a new account" page. I am trying my free, ordinary personal `Google` account, would that be the problem?

Comment: What is your `EMAIL_BACKEND` setting ?

Comment: The setting is `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is, your setting is

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend
```

This means that the [email message prints to console](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#console-backend).

> Instead of sending out real emails the console backend just writes the emails that would be sent to the standard output. By default, the console backend writes to stdout. You can use a different stream-like object by providing the stream keyword argument when constructing the connection.

Change that to

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend
```

for SMTP to work. Here is the [relevant documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/#smtp-backend)

Comment: Great, finally received the email. Thank you!

Comment: God bless you !

Answer (score 0):

Please you can add `send_mail(..other keywords like the from mail....,fail_silently=False)` this can help you get the error by default if the mail fail you wont know because it skips it

And also check the email backend if it is console or smtp make sure it is `django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend` and the host must not be localhost